# Best way to synchronize token fetching across redux sagas

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

So I want to be able to hare a common function for fetching a token, across all my sagas that hit a particular API. This is what I cam up with

```
function* getValidAuthToken(params: TokenParams) {
    // Refresh token 5 seconds before actual expiration. This gives some buffer time
    // for inflight requests to succeed
    const bufferTimeMS = 10000;

    const token = yield select(tokenSelector);
    if (token && Date.now() < token.tokenExpirationTimeStampMs - bufferTimeMS) {
        return token.tokenValue;
    }


    const isUpdating = yield select(isCurrUpdatingToken);
    // If another saga has already started the process to fetch a new token we just wait for that to finish
    if (isUpdating) {
        yield take(finishTokenUpdate);
        const token = yield select(tokenSelector);
        return token.tokenValue;
    }

    // Else we start the process to get a new lrs token
    yield put(startTokenUpdate());
    const result = yield sdk.getToken(params);
    const { tokenValue, lifetimeSeconds } = result.token;
    const tokenExpirationTimeStamp = Date.now() + lifetimeSeconds * 1000;
    yield put(finishTokenUpdate({ tokenExpirationTimeStampMs: tokenExpirationTimeStamp, tokenValue }));
    return tokenValue;
}
```

I included a piece of state `isUpdating` to avoid fetching the token if another consumer has already started the process. In such case I want to just wait for the token update to finish, and take the result.

However what I notice is that on app startup... multiple consumers call my service at the same time. In this case the `isUpdating` flag does not have time to change, and actually its a race condition weather or not `getToken` gets called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Okay actually I feel dumb.... the moment I posted this I found my mistake.

My reducer was written like this

```
import { finishTokenUpdate, startTokenUpdate } from './actions';
const isUpdatingTokenHanlder = handleActions(
    {
        startTokenupdate: (state, action) => true,
        finishTokenUpdate: (state, action) => false,
    },
    false,
);
```

This was not correctly defining my action keys. Instead it should have been

```
const isUpdatingTokenHanlder = handleActions(
    {
        [`${startTokenUpdate}`]: (state, action) => true,
      ....
);
```